# How did early MS BASIC handle "local" variables in DEF FNX(A)?

Tags: microsoft-basic

I'm not conversant enough in Intel assembler to understand what's going on in the early MS interpreters, so maybe someone can help...

Generally in MS-derived BASIC an expression would only be semi-"chunked" and in the simple cases would pretty much leave the code in its original ASCII form. For instance, `X+1` would appear that way in code.

Also, AFAIK, variable lookup occurs at runtime, so when it encounters `X` it looks through the variable table and returns/inserts it.

So how did it manage the "local" variables in DEF? For instance:

```
DEF FNX(A)=A+B+1
```

In this case, A is a "local", and B is a global and would be called like this:

```
X=FNX(10)
```

So how did it substitute the 10 into the formula?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The substitution takes place by saving the current value of `A` on the hardware stack and assigning `A` the evaluated argument for the duration of the computation. Then the variable `A` is restored from the stack.

Some more detail. A function definition is stored in the variable table (with bit 7 of the first character of its name set to mark it as a function entry).  The function definition in the variable table holds two pointers.  The first one points to the start of the expression after the `=` sign of the `DEF FN` command.  The second points to the storage of the variable that is named as the argument in the variable table.

For example, `DEF FN X(Y) = Y+1` would create a function variable named `X` (with bit 7 set) which points to the `Y+1` part in the program, and to the five bytes of storage for the variable `Y`.  When a function is invoked as, say `FN X(10)`, then

1. The argument is evaluated (resulting in `10` in the FAC).
2. The current value of the variable `Y` is pushed onto the hardware stack.
3. The variable `Y` is assigned the evaluated argument in the FAC.
4. The expression pointed to by the function `X` is evaluated (`Y + 1`).
5. And finally the value of `Y` is restored from the hardware stack.

Comment: Huh, I never suspect they would use the stack for that. And hardware stack... using the 6502 stack page? Excellent work WimC, and welcome to retro.

Comment: Yes, this is about the 6502 implementation.

Answer (score 1):

I tested this by creating two functions:

`10 A=2`
`20 B=3`
`30 DEF FNX(A)=A+B+1`
`40 DEF FNY(A)=FNX(A)+10`
`50 PRINT FNY(100),A`
`RUN`
 `114       2`
`READY.`

Since the A variable is not clobbered, it is not creating a variable. Since you can have a function call a second function without the value of the first function being clobbered, I'd suspect the value is being placed on the stack until the each function exits. If there was a place in zero page where the value was being stored, then the second function would clobber the value of the first function.

Comment: Is it possible to recursively call a function? The abort condition might be constructed by a shortcut `AND` or `OR`.

Comment: @thebusybee Both arguments of binary operators are computed first, then the result is computed. In particular, AND and OR do not short-circuit in MS BASIC.